# fpdf error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string *

Tags: php, fpdf

Ayuda con este error no se como solucionarlo. Mi version de fpdf es la 1.81 y con php 8 en la linea 144 de de Factura.php tengo `$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo)`

```js
//FUNCION EN EL ARCHIVO FPDF.PHP (string * float in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\fpdf181\fpdf.php:924)

function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')
{
    // Put an image on the page
    if($file=='')
        $this->Error('Image file name is empty');
    if(!isset($this->images[$file]))
    {
        // First use of this image, get info
        if($type=='')
        {
            $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
            if(!$pos)
                $this->Error('Image file has no extension and no type was specified: '.$file);
            $type = substr($file,$pos+1);
        }
        $type = strtolower($type);
        if($type=='jpeg')
            $type = 'jpg';
        $mtd = '_parse'.$type;
        if(!method_exists($this,$mtd))
            $this->Error('Unsupported image type: '.$type);
        $info = $this->$mtd($file);
        $info['i'] = count($this->images)+1;
        $this->images[$file] = $info;
    }
    else
        $info = $this->images[$file];

    // Automatic width and height calculation if needed
    if($w==0 && $h==0)
    {
        // Put image at 96 dpi
        $w = -96;
        $h = -96;
    }
    if($w<0)
        $w = -$info['w']*72/$w/$this->k;
    if($h<0)
        $h = -$info['h']*72/$h/$this->k;
    if($w==0)
        $w = $h*$info['w']/$info['h'];
    if($h==0)
        $h = $w*$info['h']/$info['w'];

    // Flowing mode
    if($y===null)
    {
        if($this->y+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger && !$this->InHeader && !$this->InFooter && $this->AcceptPageBreak())
        {
            // Automatic page break
            $x2 = $this->x;
            $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation,$this->CurPageSize,$this->CurRotation);
            $this->x = $x2;
        }
        $y = $this->y;
        $this->y += $h;
    }

    if($x===null)
        $x = $this->x;
    $this->_out(sprintf('q %.2F 0 0 %.2F %.2F %.2F cm /I%d Do Q',$w*$this->k,$h*$this->k,$x*$this->k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$this->k,$info['i']));
    if($link)
        $this->Link($x,$y,$w,$h,$link);
}

//FUNCION EN EL ARCHIVO EXFACTURA.PHP( C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\reportes\exFactura.php(38): PDF_Invoice->addSociete('Tecnology Cente...', '1074528547\nDire...', 'logo.png', 'png') )


//enviamos datos de la empresa al metodo addSociete de la clase factura
$pdf->addSociete(utf8_decode($empresa),
                 $documento."\n".
                 utf8_decode("Direccion: "). utf8_decode($direccion)."\n".
                 utf8_decode("Telefono: ").$telefono."\n".
                 "Email: ".$email,$logo,$ext_logo);

$pdf->fact_dev("$regv->tipo_comprobante ","$regv->serie_comprobante- $regv->num_comprobante");
$pdf->temporaire( "" );
$pdf->addDate($regv->fecha);


//FUNCION EN FACTURA.PHP (C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\reportes\Factura.php(144): FPDF->Image('logo.png', 5, 3, 25, 'png') )
function addSociete( $nom, $adresse, $logo, $ext_logo  )
{
    $x1 = 30;
    $y1 = 4;
    //Positionnement en bas
    $this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo);
    $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $nom );
    $this->Cell( $length, 2, $nom);
    $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 + 4 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $adresse );
    //Coordonnées de la société
    $lignes = $this->sizeOfText( $adresse, $length) ;
    $this->MultiCell($length, 4, $adresse);
}
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * float in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\fpdf181\fpdf.php:924 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\reportes\Factura.php(144): FPDF- >Image('logo.png', 1, 1, 1, 'png') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\reportes\exFactura.php(38): PDF_Invoice->addSociete('Tecnology Cente...', '1074528547\nDire...', 'logo.png', 'png') 
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda\fpdf181\fpdf.php on line 924
```

Comment: Creo que deberías dar más información sobre lo que haces para agregar al método `$this->Image();`. Bueno dice que estás usando un operando que no es soportado, además.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion ya agregue todos los detalles espero puedas ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función espera un height y está recibiendo la extensión del archivo en su lugar (tipo de archivo)

`$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo)`

Cámbialo por

`$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , 0 , $ext_logo)`

Donde el cero representa la medida de la altura de la imagen

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu error está en los parámetros que le pasas a tu función `Image` de fpdf, es decir, si lo notas con cuidado, este método espera los siguientes parámetros:

`function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')`

pero al tratar de usarla, pasas los siguientes: `$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo);`

Donde **$logo** a de ser un **string**, **5** iría a la variable **$x**, **3** a iría a la variable **$y**, **25** a la variable **$w** y **$ext_logo** iría a **$h**. Siendo así pues el método `Image`, hace un cálculo con esa variable, más específicamente en esta línea:

`$this->_out(sprintf('q %.2F 0 0 %.2F %.2F %.2F cm /I%d Do Q',$w*$this->k,$h*$this->k,$x*$this->k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$this->k,$info['i']));`

Entonces, en PHP, si múltiplicas un string (*png* en tu caso que es lo que veo que almacena tu variable $ext_logo) por un valor flotante, este no sabrá qué hacer y te dará un error de `Unsupported operand types` ya que no puede multiplicar un número por una cádena de texto y, creo, que ese es el problema que tienes.